# How to query Dynamodb with python data frame's column?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm able to query dynamodb using the id with fixed value (300254) using below code:

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq(300254)
for i in response['Items']:
    print(i['id'], ":", i['name'], ":", i['sal'])
```

But if i want to replace the hard coded value with my below Python dataframe (dfnew), how to query or scan in dynamodb ? dfnew has 3 fields id, name, sal and id is primary key in dynamodb. Is this possible ?

```
dfnew = pd.read_csv("C:\\babynames.csv")
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=(Key('id').eq(dfnew.id))
```

The above line of code not executing, its failing. Not giving proper error also. Is this the correct way "dfnew.id"  or any change required ?

```
response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=(Key('id').eq(dfnew.iloc[0]['id'])))
```

Tried by using above line also, but getting below error. Any help on how to achieve this ?

```
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [id] of <class 'str'>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of hard code value, i want to pass my python dataframe. Is this possible to lookup dynamodb table with the values in my dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

I did little research and below code working excellent. May be helpful to some like me.

```
itemsList = []
for i in range(len(dfnew.loc[:, 'id'])):
    response = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('id').eq(int(dfnew.at[i, 'id'])))
    itemsList += response['Items']
    df = pd.DataFrame(itemsList)

print("Record count:", df.count())
df.to_csv("C:\\outputs\\DynamoOutput.csv")
```

The above code searching Dynamodb's table by taking data from my input dataframe (dfnew.id) and giving the response in a json format. Finally able to export to CSV.